# Using the pattern attribute with html4 doctype for a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, html4

I have a script that comes equipt with built in regex for certain validation methods. I have developed the script to override the internal regex pattern with any that is found on the node being validated, as a value of the pattern attribute.

```
<input type="text" data-lazy-validator="notNull" pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$">
```

The good news is the script is working just as desired, however I now have a question about my method.

Is it safe for me to use the pattern attribute with a view that has an html4.01 doctype? I am not looking to use any built in validation (as I know html4.01 did not have this) but instead use this as a hook for my script to do what I said above.

Comment: Then why not convert it to a `data-pattern` attribute for example?

Comment: Because he said html4 doctype

Comment: I need it to fallback gracefully for Non-js or JS disabled. Data-pattern will not be recognized as a native call to the browsers default validation handling in HTML5 browsers.

Comment: Turns out that data-* attributes will work without error in browsers IE 6+. This is not the issue, and would solve the problem aside from the above mentioned fallback.